# Trying to create a dynamic UI in an R Shiny app based on the sum of other inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have an R Shiny app with which I'm trying to create a dynamic UI based on the sum of other inputs. See my minimal reprex below:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(tidyverse)

    ui <- fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                numericInput(inputId = "starting_qbs",
                             label = "Number of starting QBs",
                             value = 1,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 6),
                numericInput(inputId = "starting_rbs",
                             label = "Number of starting RBs",
                             value = 2,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 6),
                numericInput(inputId = "starting_wrs",
                             label = "Number of starting WRs",
                             value = 3,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 6),
                numericInput(inputId = "starting_tes",
                             label = "Number of starting TEs",
                             value = 1,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 6),
                numericInput(inputId = "starting_flex",
                             label = "Number of starting flex spots",
                             value = 1,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 6),
                conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "sum(input.starting_qbs, 
                                     input.starting_rbs, 
                                     input.starting_wrs,
                                     input.starting_tes,
                                     input.starting_flex) >= 1", 
                    selectInput("draft_pick_1",
                                "Round 1 Selection",
                                c("Select player" ="", projections$player))),

                selectInput("draft_pick_2",
                            "Round 2 Selection",
                            c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
                selectInput("draft_pick_3",
                            "Round 3 Selection",
                            c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
                selectInput("draft_pick_4",
                            "Round 4 Selection",
                            c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
                selectInput("draft_pick_5",
                            "Round 5 Selection",
                            c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
                selectInput("draft_pick_6",
                            "Round 6 Selection",
                            c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
                selectInput("draft_pick_7",
                            "Round 7 Selection",
                            c("Select player" ="", projections$player))
            ),
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("draftPlot"))
        )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
    renderPrint("This is text")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The first section asks how many starting QBs, RBs, etc. a lineup has. From there, I want as many of the "draft_pick_X" selectInput options to show up as there are from the sum of all of the inputs above. For example, if you have 6 total roster spots, then 6 of the "draft_pick_X" inputs will appear, so on and so forth. What I included was my first attempt at trying to do this for draft_pick_1, but that didn't work. Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `uiOutput` with rendering inputs in server, is the way to go.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(inputId = "starting_qbs",
                   label = "Number of starting QBs",
                   value = 1,
                   min = 0,
                   max = 6),
      numericInput(inputId = "starting_rbs",
                   label = "Number of starting RBs",
                   value = 2,
                   min = 0,
                   max = 6),
      numericInput(inputId = "starting_wrs",
                   label = "Number of starting WRs",
                   value = 3,
                   min = 0,
                   max = 6),
      numericInput(inputId = "starting_tes",
                   label = "Number of starting TEs",
                   value = 1,
                   min = 0,
                   max = 6),
      numericInput(inputId = "starting_flex",
                   label = "Number of starting flex spots",
                   value = 1,
                   min = 0,
                   max = 6),
      uiOutput('draftUI'),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("players")
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  total <- reactive(input$starting_qbs + input$starting_rbs + input$starting_wrs + input$starting_tes + input$starting_flex)
  output$draftUI <- renderUI({
    count <- total()
    list <- seq(count)
    list <- lapply(list, function(x) selectInput(paste0("draft_pick_",x),
                                                 paste0("Round ", x, " Selection"),
                                                 c("Select player" ="", projections$player)))


    tagList(list)
  })

  drafted_players <- reactive({

    # If you did not make the total() reactive for some reason you can use this method to get any arbitrary number of inputs that match a pattern
    # names(input)[grepl('draft_pick_',names(input), fixed = T)] %>% sort() %>% sapply(function(x) input[[x]])

   paste0('draft_pick_',1:total()) %>% sapply(function(x) input[[x]])

  })

  output$players <- renderText({
    drafted_players()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to then get the list of players selected from each selectInput so that I can use them on a plot? 

Previously I had something like this as a way to filter the names:


`        drafted_players <- reactive({
            draft_picks <- c(input$draft_pick_1,
                             input$draft_pick_2,
                             input$draft_pick_3,
                             input$draft_pick_4)
            vor_table() %>% 
                filter(player %in% draft_picks)
        })`

How could I replicate this with your renderUI?

Comment: I've edited the answer. I used `renderText` instead of `renderPlot`, since I don't know what plot you're trying to make. You can use the inputs values to filter from a dataframe if you want.

Comment: Okay, so by doing this, does "drafted_players" become a list of the inputs that were chosen for each "draft_pick_X" option? Sorry for all the questions, but appreciate the help @Muzammil Aziz!

Comment: Yes, a vector to be precise

Comment: If you want the `reactive` to return a filtered data frame like you mentioned in your comment, you can assign the vector to a variable like `picks <- paste0('draft_pick_',1:total()) %>% sapply(function(x) input[[x]])` and then filter `picks` from the data frame in the next line.